# SwiftUI get the index of a Picker element in the onChange event

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I would like to get the index of the user selection in a Picker but on the onChange event of the picker.

Below is my code:

```
Picker("Username", selection: $selectedOption) {
                        
    ForEach(options, id: \.self) {
                            
        Text($0)
    }
                        
}
.id(UUID())
.pickerStyle(.menu)
.onChange(of: selectedOption) { newValue in
                        
    print("Username:", selectedOption + " " + index) <---- Error here
                        
}
```

how do i get the index?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask for the index

```
.onChange(of: selectedOption) { newValue in
    let index = options.firstIndex(of: newValue)!                 
    print("Username:", selectedOption + " " + index)
                        
}
```

Comment: man soooo simple... thx for this!!